# Hbase Partial Rowkey Filter with multiple/range of values

Tags: filter, hbase

I have a hbase table where my rowkey is dayinyear+customerinfo. I have only partial rowkey ie., dayinyear. I want to get all rows falling between any consecutive days of a year(Ex:182 & 183) in single scan. I used PrefixFilter by passing single day(Ex:182). But how to provide both values in filter so that it should return me all rows starting with rowkey 182 and 183. I tried FilterList, but its not working.

Sample Data:

```
ROW       
181abcd   
181efgh   
182dkdk   
182jfhg   
183sdfj   
184sdjf
```

Expecting only the following set of rows should be returned

```
182dkdk   
182jfhg   
183sdfj
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
scan 'TABLE_NAME',{STARTROW=>'182',ENDROW=>'184'}
```

where  STARTROWPREFIX <= rowkey < ENDROWPREFIX

which will give you output as

```
182dkdk
182jfhg
183sdfj
```